# using :not to select elements

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a table of values. I wish to add up all the values from the final column of the table. Using this works as the final column cells all share a similar class `"total-cell"`:

```
var elements = element.all(by.css('tr > td > .total-cell'))
```

I now wish to ignore certain rows (`tr`) from the list. The `tr` I wish to ignore has a class called `ng-hide` in common, so I added a not statement to my selector, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

```
var elements = element.all(by.css('tr:not(.ng-hide) > td > .total-cell'))
```

Running the second selector statement has the same effect as the first (it's as if the `ng-hide` property is being ignored?)

Comment: Are you sure `ng-hide` is a class, not an attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presence of [`ng-hide` class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) makes an element invisible according to the specification:

> The `.ng-hide` CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the `display` style to `none`.

This means we can just *filter the visible rows* of the table only:

```
var rows = element.all(by.css('tr > td > .total-cell'));
var visibleRows = rows.filter(function (row) {
    return row.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed;
    });
});
expect(visibleRows.getText()).toEqual(['10', '20', '30']);
```